# Trying to grab specific number from variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So Im trying to write this code where the character's passive skill gets interrupted when he is hit. The way I want to do that is by having the program grab the characters health value from the health variable and check against it every frame to see if its dropped.

However, after researching I cant seem to find a way to actually do this. Grab a number from the variable without the new variable being effected by it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might have more luck on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During each frame use another variable to store the last known value of the health variable, then compare the variables to see if they have different values. For example:

```
int health = 100;
int lastFrameHealth;

void Start ()
{
    lastFrameHealth = health;
}

void Update ()
{
    if (health < lastFrameHealth)
    {
        StartCoroutine("InterruptPassiveSkill", 5f);
    }

    lastFramehealth = health;
}


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    health -= 10;
}

IEnumerator InterruptPassiveSkill (float seconds)
{
    // insert code to deactivate passive skill here:

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds); // delay for number of seconds

    // insert code to reactivate passive skill here:

}
```

The coroutine used in this example is a nice, easy way to add a delay.  Coroutines also make simple state machines much quicker to create.  Coroutines are a Unity feature, non-native to C#.